# How can I contact KLM Ground Services?

Tags: airports, check-in, ams, kenya-airways

I'm trying to find an E-Mail address, or at least a phone number, to KLM Ground Services at Schiphol airport.

I can only find the main KLM contact number, however, which is utterly useless in providing the answers I need.

Comment: The official website for Schiphol airport [lists all handling agents](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/company-directory/logistics-and-storage/handling-agents/) and has a page for each airline operating there but the [contact for Kenya Airlines indeed seems to be KLM](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/airline/kenya-airways/).

Comment: @Relaxed KLM Ground Services in other words. Great, now to find a contact number/address to them (as opposed to the KLM call centre)

Comment: Is it the [KLM Aircraft Services Contract Management Department (SPL/KG)](https://www.klm.com/aircraftservices/en/contact.html)? infoaircraftservices@klm.com Fax: +31(0)20-64 81388 ... it omits phone number(s), likely deliberate

Comment: What is it that you want to ask them?

Comment: Hrm -- is this more of an Aviation.SE question?

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject No, because I'm trying to contact check-in staff about a travel question. I'm 100% sure that it's KLM Ground Services I need, and absolutely no one else (the KLM reservations team couldn't help me)

Comment: Did you end up finding out?

Comment: @JonathanReez No

Answer (score 2):

KLM Equipment services at Schiphol airport is listed on [the official Schiphol airport website](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/company-directory/air-services/aircraft-maintenance/).

Their phone number is

> +31206492236

Maybe they could put you in touch with the KLM "Ground Services" you seek? I am unsure what you mean by "Ground Services", as I have never heard of such a thing.

Also, you could try [KLM CityHopper BV](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/company-directory/logistics-and-storage/airlines/) (in the logistics and storage directory for Schiphol airport).

Their phone number is

> +31206492373

Maybe they *too* could put you in touch with the people at KLM you want to speak to?

For [general Schiphol baggage services](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/company-directory/other-services/baggage-services/), you can call them at their number listed on their directory website.

Their phone number is

> +31207952828